# Execution failed ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug' com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

**build .gradle** this is `build.gradle`, *I have been getting this error for the last 5 hours. I have found no information about how to solve this.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**APP leven BUILD gradle** this is my app level build.gradle

See my all dependencies, what is the error?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.intraday.geeks"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this please, change the following lines of code:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.0.4'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:4.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
```

See [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) more informations.

Comment: `Execution failed ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug' com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
` is an error not a warning.

Comment: I'm saying that according to your answer... if `compile` was a problem then it will only raise a warning not an error

Comment: Oh, I understand. We can also remove that warning. Let's wait to see what the OP says.

Comment: @AlexMamo after changing librery according to your suggestions that error was resolved but now one more error is thier

Comment: I'll also take a look at your second question.

Comment: @AlexMamo please help me on another question too